# Deployed SSIS Package not reflecting changes made to package

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have made changes to my SSIS package within MS Visual Studio 2019 (MS VS 2019). When I deploy my changed package to the Integration Services Catalog and re-run the job the changes don't appear to have been reflected. The change I made was to add a truncate and re-load to a staging table. I know it's not working because after the job has run the staging table does not have any records. When I manually run the project from within MS VS 2019 it works (i.e. the staging table is populated).

I've tried deploying the project from MS VS 2019, deploying just the package from MS VS 2019 as well as copying the package file from its location on my local machine to the directory on the MS SQL Server machine accessed by the SSIS catalog. None of these seem to work.

Comment: Did you try to open the SQL Agent job and refresh the package. Sometimes you just need to open the job and reselect the ssis package and it works. If that also does not work then check the build version of SSIS package deployed in SQL Server if it is same as the one in Visual Studio

Comment: Hi Ritika, thanks for your quick response. I tried your suggestion without any luck. just so that I can confirm that I am following your steps correctly could you please send me screen shots of where you check the build version in Visual Studio and SQL Server? Thanks

Comment: Try to execute the below query in your SQL Server in SSISDB database to get the version number of SSIS package deployed                    ```Select pkg.* from [internal].[packages] pkg
join [internal].[projects] prj
on pkg.project_id = prj.project_id
and pkg.project_version_lsn = prj.object_version_lsn
where pkg.name = <Package_Name> ```                                                                    To check in Visual Studio, right click in the Control Flow area of the package and click on Properties. You will be able to see the build version

Comment: Hi Ritika, thanks for your suggestion. I have checked the build version in Visual Studio and SQL Server and they are the same:

Comment: Sorry, I tried to post a screen shot showing the same version number but couldn't work out how to. One thing that I did notice is that the version_guid is different between Visual Studio and SQL Server (but the version build number is the same). Is the mismatched version guid of any significance? Thanks

Comment: No, the same thing happened with me in past and even updating the mismatched guid version did not helped. Try creating the new job again or delete the particular step and create it again. What happens when you run the SSIS Package itself in Integration Service Catalogs? Does it run the old or new version.

Answer (score 2):

I already met this issue.
Are you deploying at project level with a .ispac or at package level ? In both case, I suspect a bug with the build of your project. In your solution directory, try to delete the .ispac located in the bin/ folder. You can also delete the content of the obj/ folder ( to be safe, move it in another folder in case you have to restore it). Then rebuild your solution in Visual Studio. The .ispac/.dtsx files should be updated a'd ready to deploy.

I hope it helps. :-)

Comment: Thanks Hugo. I tried your solution but unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: Maybe you should drop the deployed project and redeploy it "from scratch" and reconfigure parameters / connection managers. At least you shouldn't have an "old" version installed... :-s

Comment: Worked for me! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You must rebuild your SSIS project by visual studio data tools and then deploy newly generated project file in sql server integration services catalog.