# Deploying updated SSIS package doesn't work

Tags: deployment, visual-studio-2015, ssis, sql-server-2016, ssis-projects

**The problem**

So I am running into an interesting issue. I have been tasked to change a query for a simple SSIS package in Visual Studio 2015, which is a thing I have done multiple times in the last 6 months.

After changing the package and deploying it (to an installation of SQL server 2016, without errors!) I noticed that the execution of the package (scheduled with SSMS) generates the same result as the pre-updated package, meaning the demanded changes hadn't taken effect. Of course, as test, I have executed the package directly from VS2015 and got the result I wanted.

Ever since I have been running tests and trying to find a solution. The problems seems to lie with the receiving side of the deployment proces.

**What I have tried**

- Deleted the package from the existing project in SSMS and redeployed. Deployment again seemd to succeed but the package didn't show up, so I had to restore an old version of the project.
- Deploy the package from multiple different computers with access to VS2015 and the source code. No change...
- Deploy the package to a new (empty) SSMS project: package does not appear in the project. This leads me to believe that the old package is kept when I publish the new version to the existing project in SSMS.
- Regenating/rebuilding the package in VS2015, frankly this was never necessary and probably doesn't do anything for an SSIS package, but it may help you get an idea of my skill level.
- In the past we have had issues with the encryption level blocking the deployment of packages. I have verified these settings and found no issues.
- I have verified if any updates have recently been installed to the database server, which does not seem to be the case.
- I have (of course) tried to google the issue, which is tricky due to the lack of errors. I have found the following links, that describe the same/a similar issue, but their solutions haven't helped:
- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/259672/ssis-package-not-being-deployed
- [Deployed SSIS Package not reflecting changes made to package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57486629/deployed-ssis-package-not-reflecting-changes-made-to-package/57489360#57489360)

**What is still left to try**

- Rebuild project from scratch to see if that version is deployable.

Unfortunately I don't have a lot of experience with this subject and no colleagues or contacts to ask for help.

Thanks in advance.

---

**My workaround**

After quite a bit of time attempting to solve the issue I have resorted to working around the problem, by manually importing the .ispac file into the database. While this is not the prettiest of solutions, at least it's a workable one. If anyone has any other idea's I'll gladly see them, but for now the issue isn't nearly as pressing as it was.

Comment: delete the package in the deployed location and then deploy it again

Comment: also, you can make the sql a parameter and pass that along from agent when calling the package to run. this makes it so that you wouldn't need to deploy the package again for just a SQL change.

Comment: @KeithL thanks for the ideas. I failed to list I have already deleted the package before deploying the new version, which unfortunately resulted in an empty projet. Your suggestion to add the query as a parameter is a good idea, unfortunately I will of course have to be able to deploy another version of the package which right now appears to be impossible..

Answer (score 0):

From your post. "Deleted the package from the existing project in SSMS and redeployed. Deployment again seemd to succeed but the package didn't show up".

Are you 100% sure you are deploying it to the same project on the same server on the database?  Are you refreshing after you deploy?

Comment: Thanks for your reply (and my apologies for the delay on my end). Yes, there's only one server in our environment that's used to publish packages like this to, and I have refreshed the overview after publishing (also tried to reconnect myself, to really force a refresh, just in case).

Unfortunately that hasn't changed anything..

Comment: @Arne, any findings on this. I have the same issue and have been struggling for a couple days now trying to figure out why I am not able to see the deployed packages. Thank you.

Comment: @Yoismel, I haven't been working with the system much lately but I have resolved my issue by simply generating my solution in Visual Studio and then publishing the .dtsx directly in SQL Server Manager. It neatly replaces the existing package with the same name and has fixed the problem for me, even if it means the process is now less simple than it was before.

Edit: I just noticed I apparently published the .ispac as a workaround (see the update on my original post) so at this point I'm not fully certain if it's the .dtsx or the .ispac you need to publish.